# Best way to limit sql row updates to 1 per 24 hour period

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have an asp.net gridview that populates from a table and has the edit functionality enabled. Im not sure if there is anything built into sql that I can use for this limitation, or if I am going to have to make a time stamp column to keep track. If that is the only method how would I integrate that into the gridview?

im not sure the best way to go about doing this.

It might be an option to populate two gridviews, one pulling the editable rows (not edited in the last 24 hr) and the 2nd being the ones they edit. the only difference being the select statement for each. im not sure this is the best way tho.

The columns are PK (primary and identity), ResidentName, ResidentAddress, VisitorNumber, VisitorName. I can add a datetime column if I need to.

thanks

mike

Comment: create a column called LastUpdated, check its value if > DateTime.Now - 24 or not?

Comment: Can you provide the list of columns that you currently have in SQL?

Comment: The columns are PK (primary and identity), ResidentName, ResidentAddress, VisitorNumber, VisitorName. I can add a datetime column if I need to.

I can certainly do the if > 24hours. but im not sure how I would change each row of the gridview to accommodate each since the select would have rows mixed with each.

Comment: Why can't you add a date time column and pull only those rows which are not updated in 24 hours? That way you don't need to modify grid. Using PK, you can update the new column whenever you're updating database from grid.

Comment: They still need to see the ones that have been updated recently. Just not be able to edit them.

Comment: @That will work, but I think only if there are 2 gridviews. one for the editable rows, one for the non editable rows.

This is what I have so far ("ken set manually instead of the parameter"). The current data is 2016-11-05 03:10:01.253

SELECT * FROM [RegisteredVisitors] WHERE ([ResidentName] = 'Ken' AND [Date] <  (SELECT getdate() -1)) 

This returned 1 row with a date of 2016-11-03 03:10:13.493 (two days ago)

but this is not necessarily 24 hours. So they could set one row at 11 pm, then at 12:01 it would let him change again. I need to compare hours.

Comment: (SELECT getdate()) -1) gets 1 day ago. but 11:59 to 1:01 is "one day ago". I need 24 hours ago.

Comment: SELECT * FROM [RegisteredVisitors] WHERE ([ResidentName] = 'Ken' AND [Date] <  (SELECT DateAdd(SECOND, -86400, getdate())))

I believe this will do it.

Comment: @Pratik Gaikwad

thank you. works great and more user friendly with two types of data in two different views

Answer (score 1):

If you working with `DataSet` in c# there is methods to check changes using `ds.HasChanges()` and also you can get changed rows by using `ds.GetChanges()`. Can check rows `Added` or `Modified`. Thereafter you can bind `ds` to `DataGridView`.

Comment: I didn't try it, but it does look like a great option so ill vote you up. becuase i knew how to do it from above, i made 2 tables, and kind of like having the two different datatypes in very separate tables. looks cleaner. but i wanted to thank you for the advice and info